# THREE.js blur the frame buffer

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, framebuffer

I need to blur the frame buffer and I don't know how to get the frame buffer using THREE.js.

**I want to blur the whole frame buffer rather than blur each textures in the scene.** So I guess I should read the frame buffer and then blur, rather than doing this in shaders.

Here's what I have tried:

Call when init:

```
var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(512, 512, {
    wrapS: THREE.RepeatWrapping,
    wrapT: THREE.RepeatWrapping,
    minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    type: THREE.FloatType,
    stencilBuffer: false,
    depthBuffer: true
});
renderTarget.generateMipmaps = false;
```

Call in each frame:

```
var gl = renderer.getContext();

// render to target
renderer.render(scene, camera, renderTarget, false);
framebuffer = renderTarget.__webglFramebuffer;
console.log(framebuffer);

gl.flush();
if (framebuffer != null)
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
var width = height = 512;
var rdData = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, rdData);
console.log(rdData);

// render to screen
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

But `framebuffer` is *`WebFramebuffer {}`* and `rdData` is full of `0`. Am I doing this in the right way?

Comment: That doesn't blur "each textures in the scene."

Comment: @NicolBolas Then, how should I blur the whole scene in detail?

Comment: I think you will find this post insightful to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077762/three-js-shader-texture-blinking

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any blur should use shaders to be efficient, but in this case not as materials.

If you want to blur the entire frame buffer and render that to the screen use the effect composer. It's located in three.js/examples/js./postprocessing/EffectComposer.js

Set up the scene camera and renderer as normal but in addition add an instance of the effect composer. With the scene as a render pass.

```
composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
```

Then blur the whole buffer with two passes using the included blur shaders located in three.js/examples/shaders/

```
hblur = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.HorizontalBlurShader );
composer.addPass( hblur );
            
vblur = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.VerticalBlurShader );
// set this shader pass to render to screen so we can see the effects
vblur.renderToScreen = true;
composer.addPass( vblur );
```

finally in your method called in each frame render using the composer instead of the renderer

```
composer.render();
```

Here is a [link](https://mrdoob.com/projects/htmleditor/) to a working example of full screen blur

Comment: I will blur the whole scene depending on the depth information of each pixel, so I still need to get the framebuffer rather than add `HorizontalBlurShader` for the whole scene.

Comment: it sounds like you're trying to do a depth of field blur. The process is similar and the blurring will still be handled by a shader and be written back out to a full screen quad. I have a working example of depth of field here http://www.andrewberg.com/prototypes/threejs/bokeh/

Comment: great answer, thanks for the link! do i understand correctly that "effectscomposer" library works independently from the rest of the three renderer? that it takes anything that is inside the renderer as a 2d image and applies filter on it? (i am asking because i would like to blur the image and the threshold it in order to achieve "wobbly" effect)

Comment: That's correct all the effects are applied to a 2d image in a post processing step.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the code snippet worked very well for me, easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [MeshDepthMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshDepthMaterial) and render this into your shader.

I suggest rendering the blur pass with a dedicated camera using the same settings as the scene's diffuse camera. Then by adjusting the camera's frustrum you can do both screen and depth of blur effects. For a screen setup move the near frustrum towards the camera and move the far frustrum in increments away from the camera.

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshDepthMaterial