# Three.js: how to create blur glass wall

Tags: three.js

I want to create glass wall with some effect for more realistic look. (little smoked or blur effect). How can I add this effect to my material? (I have only color,opacity and transparency now). Sry if it is a stupid question, I am beginner.

Thx for reactions :)

Answer (score 1):

Blurring the framebuffer has nothing to do with refractive glass. Take a look at:
http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/#webgl_materials_shaders_fresnel
and
http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction

and search for "refraction shader" or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the shaders.
Basically for a blur:

- you render your image into a frame buffer
- you apply a first horizontal pass on the frame buffer and render into another frame buffer
- you apply a second vertical pass on the the second fbo back to the original one
- you need to render the frame buffer on the screen

Take a look on this thread: [THREE.js blur the frame buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354117/three-js-blur-the-frame-buffer)